# Read a byte from configuration file python

Tags: python-3.x, config, password-encryption

I am trying to read an encrypted password(base 64+AES encoding) that is stored in configuration file. I have to make use of limited libraries , because of which I can't try many of the encryption methods which I found.

The code I am using is

```
def encrypt_password():                     # for encryption
    from Crypto.Cipher import AES
    obj = AES.new('This is a key123', AES.MODE_CFB, 'This is an IV456')
    message = "password$1"
    ciphertext = obj.encrypt(message) #ciphertext is the encrypted password
```

I am placing the ciphertext as enc_password in the configuration file

For decryption

```
def decrypt_password():
    from Crypto.Cipher import AES
    cipher_text=RPF.readfromConfigFile('LoginCredentials','enc_password')
    obj2 = AES.new('This is a key123', AES.MODE_CFB, 'This is an IV456')
    message = obj2.decrypt(cipher_text)
    message = message.decode("utf-8")    #gives the decrypted password
```

The problem I am facing is that while reading from configuration file, the encrypted password is read as a string while it should be a byte(I believe). This is how I read from the configuration file:

```
if moduleName == 'LoginCredentials':
            import io
            config.read('configuration.INI')
            list_of_variables = [config.get('LoginCredentials', 'url'), config.get('LoginCredentials', 'UserName'),
                                 config.get('LoginCredentials', 'enc_password')]
```

Hope you guys can provide a solution..
    `

Comment: What error messages are you getting?

Comment: Error is      UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 2: invalid start byte

Comment: Use a debugger to see the value of `message` before you decode it.

Comment: b'\xef\x1b[\xc2r?\xaa\xfcK^\xda\xce$X\xe9 \xfc\xac' is the message before decoding with utf-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using config.ini to store encrypted password, I have started using .enc files.

For writing to an enc file:

```
    with open('file.enc', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(b'abcdefg')
```

For reading from enc file:

```
    with open("file.enc", "rb") as f:
    iv = f.read(16)
```

This worked!!!!